# Basic combinatorics question, can you help me?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Before I start let me thank anyone that contributes to helping me with an answer for this.
Ok - on to the question. Assume you have 10 jelly beans, 5 yellow and 5 red. 
What is the total amount of ways that they can be arranged in a line assuming there is no difference between the jelly beans within a specific colour? 
Another way of saying this is 'I have two jelly beans of different colours, they get placed back to be chosen from again after use. How many different combinations can be made?'
Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm not so sure how the second statement is another way of saying the first. Are you sure they're saying the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $10$ placeholders, and you choose the $5$ places where the yellow beans will go: ${10 \choose 5}=252$ possibilities.

---

Regarding the second statement and your comment:

If, by *Catalan word*, you actually mean *[Dyck word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language)*, then the answer is easy: for a length $2n$, you have ${2n \choose n}$ possible words with two symbols, out of which $C_n$ are Dyck words, with $C_n$ the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):

$$C_n=\frac1{n+1}{2n \choose n}$$

So your probability would be $\dfrac1{n+1}$.

Comment: Assuming you fix the red beans, wouldn't there be six places for beans to go?

Comment: No. You number the places: you pick $5$ numbers among $\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$, so $5$ numbers remain available. With you approach, if you place the $5$ yellow beans together, you may place the $5$ red ones before of after: two possibilities. But they account for the two choices $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ for the yellow ones.

Comment: Ah right, thought you were doing something else. Nevermind, makes sense now.

Comment: So would the second statement be the same if I have the clause that you had to have 5 and 5? Basically I'm solving a problem about the probability that a string of length 10 with 5 A's and 5 B's will be a catalan word. @Sp3000